# How to log an element's text in cypress.io after failure

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a Cypress.io test using following command to fail the test after `[data-cy=error]` appears. I want to modify it to throw the text before failing the test. Do you have any solutions that how I can log the text?

```
cy.get('[data-cy=error]', {timeout: 10000})  
  .should('not.exist')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use cy.log(yourTextHere)](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/log.html#Syntax). That should work.

Comment: Of course, but I want to log the text for the element with `[data-cy=error]`, if it does exist.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Cypress commands return promises, so at some point you should be able to put a catch handler, either as a second argument, or explicitly with .catch()?

Comment: Hmm, so you mean instead of using `.should()`, I can use `.catch()`. The main issue is parsing and logging the element's text when I'm using the same command.